I would like to upload images and json to the back end
I am trying to upload images and json but the backend can't get my images. I have a response 200 indicating the api call is successful but backend can't get images
func ChamaDataField(fieldName: String, fileName: String, data: Data, mimeType: String) -> String {
    var fieldString = ""
    fieldString += "--\(boundary)\r\n"
    fieldString += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(fieldName)\"; filename=\"\(fileName)\"\r\n"
    fieldString += "Content-Type: \(mimeType)\r\n\r\n"
    fieldString += String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
    fieldString += "\r\n"
    return fieldString
}

func chamaTextField(named name: String, value: String) -> Data {
    var fieldString = ""
    fieldString += "--\(boundary)\r\n"
    fieldString += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(name)\"\r\n\r\n"
    fieldString += value
    fieldString += "\r\n"
    return Data(fieldString.utf8)
}


private func myFormDataCallTwo(requestBody model: chamaOfficialsPhotoUploadRequestTwo, documentName: String, documentData: UIImage?, _ completion: @escaping (Bool, String?) -> ()) {
         
    let baseUrl = "https://mbankingtest.postbank.co.ke:9193/"
    let endpointPath = "mchama/api/gateway/files"
    
    guard let url = URL(string: baseUrl + endpointPath) else {
        completion(false, "Invalid URL")
        return
    }
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    
    guard let sessionValue = AppConfig.AppStore["sessionId"] as? String else {
        print("Failed to retrieve session ID")
        completion(false, nil)
        return
    }

    request.setValue(sessionValue, forHTTPHeaderField: "session_id")
    
    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    
    var body = Data()
    
    guard let documentsData = documentData else {
        completion(false, "document data is nil")
        return
    }
    
    guard let imageData = documentsData.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.7) else {
        completion(false, "Failed to convert UIImage to Data")
        return
    }
    guard let jsonData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(model) else {
        completion(false, "Failed to encode model to json")
        return
    }
    
    //append the image data
    
    let filePart = ChamaDataField(fieldName: "files", fileName: "\(documentName).jpg", data: imageData, mimeType: "image/jpeg")
    body.append(Data(filePart.utf8))

    
    let imageHex = imageData.prefix(20).map { String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joined()
        print("Image Data (first 20 bytes as hex): \(imageHex)")
    //appending the json part
    
    body.append(chamaTextField(named: "data", value: String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!))
    
    //closing the body
    
    body.append("--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
    

    
    // Debug: Print JSON data
    
    if let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) {
        print("JSON being sent: \(jsonString)")
    }
    
    
    // Debug: Print final assembled body in chunks
        let bodyStringComponents = [
            String(data: body.prefix(100), encoding: .utf8) ?? "", // Print first 100 bytes
            "..."
        ]
        print("Request body: \(bodyStringComponents.joined())")
    
    request.httpBody = body
    
    for (key, value) in request.allHTTPHeaderFields ?? [:] {
        print("My Header - \(key) : \(value)")
    }

    
    if let bodyString = String(data: body, encoding: .utf8) {
        print("Reequest body: \(bodyString)")
    }
    
    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: request) {(data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            completion(false, error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        
        if let response = response {
            print("REsponse: \(response)")
        }
        
        if let data = data {
            do {
                let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
                if let dataValue = jsonObject?["data"] as? String {
                    print("Document was uploaded successfully. identifier: \(dataValue)")
                } else {
                    print("Document uploaded successfully but failed to parse response")
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error decoding JSON response: \(error)")
            }
        }

        
       
        
    }.resume()
    
}


fieldString += String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "" for an image, that's your issue...

fieldString += String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""

That's your issue if data is an image...
Read fieldString, you'll see that it's certainly "" at that place.
Instead:
func ChamaDataField(fieldName: String, fileName: String, data: Data, mimeType: String) -> Data {
    var fieldData = Data()
    fieldData += Data("--\(boundary)\r\n".utf8)
    fieldData += Data("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(fieldName)\"; filename=\"\(fileName)\"\r\n".utf8)
    fieldData += Data("Content-Type: \(mimeType)\r\n\r\n".utf8)
    fieldData += data
    fieldData += Data("\r\n".utf8)
    return fieldData
}

In use:
let filePart = ChamaDataField(fieldName: "files", fileName: "\(documentName).jpg", data: imageData, mimeType: "image/jpeg")
body.append(filePart)

